# space at the bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I've created the following demo to show my issue:

http://francisbaptiste.com/nov17/

Each div is 33.33% wide. Within the div is an image with 100% width. I want it to be a perfect grid of images, but the height of the div is always a little more than the height of the image.

Shouldn't the height of the div be set by the height of the image within it? So why is there that little bit of space at the bottom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gap is coming from the actual whitespace after the image tag. You can use this to fix it:

```
.card img {
    display: block;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/2hx9w3Lo/)

Or a more hacky solution:

```
.card {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/2hx9w3Lo/1/)

Comment: Now, what puzzles me is why does the gap still remain even after manually glueing all the elements together (`</div><div><img></div>`etc...)

Comment: It has something to do with the `line-height` - see http://jsfiddle.net/ktqwgh14/1/

Comment: @JakeParis, thank you, that's brilliant!! I guess inline elements assume there's a line of text present. Or something...

Comment: This was driving me crazy yesterday. Can't believe it was such a simple oversight. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. It's one of those things you never forget after you solve it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the problem is the height of outer div, you cannot use auto since the browser may have some default action for the div and its inside content. Instead, I specify the percentage of height and solved the problem

```
.card {
width: 33.333%;
height: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Try resizing your window and see how that method fails. It will also fail when/if images change size.